# how to make springboot support h2c in tomcat9?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, http2, tomcat9, spring-boot-2

I try for this,a new connector was made to try to support h2c,whent i try to use the curl send http2 request,An error occurred on the server;
environment：
springboot 2.1.4
tomcat 9
jdk 1.8

```
@Bean
public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(createH2cConnector());
    tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers();
    return tomcat;
}

private Connector createH2cConnector() {
    Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
    Http2Protocol upgradeProtocol = new Http2Protocol();
    connector.addUpgradeProtocol(upgradeProtocol);
    connector.setPort(5080);
    return connector;
}
```

Error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:551)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:336)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: This error is due to my attempt to get a new connector to upgrade the server to receive h2c requests

Comment: today i find my maven has dependency diff tomcat version ,so they clash,i want to close this question but i dont know how to do it ,someone can help me ?